# Spring Batch JdbcPagingItemReader paging not work

Tags: java, spring-batch

I use spring batch to do a data migration job. there are a lot of data so that I decided to use the JdbcPagingItemReader to read the data by page.
Below is how I define the reader:

```
private JdbcPagingItemReader<Map<String, Object>> buildItemReader(final DataSource dataSource, String tableName,
        String tenant){

    String tenantName = tenantHelper.determineTenant(tableName);

    Map<String, Object> sqlParameterValues = new HashMap<>();
    sqlParameterValues.put("tableName", tableName);
    sqlParameterValues.put("tenantName", tenantName);
    sqlParameterValues.put("tenant", tenant);

    JdbcPagingItemReader<Map<String, Object>> itemReader = new JdbcPagingItemReader<>();
    itemReader.setDataSource(dataSource);
    itemReader.setPageSize(2);
    itemReader.setFetchSize(2);
    itemReader.setQueryProvider(generateSqlPagingQueryProvider(tableName,tenantName,tenant));
    //itemReader.setParameterValues(sqlParameterValues);
    itemReader.setRowMapper(new ColumnMapRowMapper());
    try {
        itemReader.afterPropertiesSet();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return itemReader;
}

private PostgresPagingQueryProvider generateSqlPagingQueryProvider(String tableName, String tenantName,
        String tenant) {
    PostgresPagingQueryProvider provider = new PostgresPagingQueryProvider();
    Map<String, Order> sortKeys = new LinkedHashMap<>();
    String sortKey = getSortKeyBytable(tableName);
    sortKeys.put(sortKey, Order.ASCENDING);

    provider.setSelectClause("select *");
    provider.setFromClause("from " + tableName);
    provider.setWhereClause("where " + tenantName + " ='" + tenant + "'");
    provider.setSortKeys(sortKeys);
    return provider;
}
```

the sortkey I specified is the primary key in the table, it is a string. But the paging is not working as expected. But it throws no error it just read all the data.

In the spring batch document, it provides an example which use the int type id as the sort key, I am wondering if the spring batch paging read only support the int type sort key word? And can not support the string sort key?

Is this a limitation of spring batch?

Comment: Looking at the comment `the String compare did work. But the paging still not work for me. The reader just read all the data into the memory.`: I think your issue is related to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55390995 (See my answer there). The sort key can be of any type and the paging is working fine. It is your Postgresql driver that is loading all data in memory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its not a limitation of spring batch.
This is how a database works.
It sorts string based on its ascii value.

Comment: Thanks, the String compare did work. But the paging still not work for me. The reader just read all the data into the memory.

Comment: Can you check the query generated by spring batch? Set configuration logging.level.org.springframework.batch.item.database=DEBUG

Comment: Below is the query generated by spring batch, I tried it in the sql editor ,it is right, but the memory still did not get released after each chunk :                   
                                                                                                                 SELECT * FROM custom_amount WHERE (tenant_id ='bf2e8407-5fa3-4137-9683-75d4e95c8c6c') AND ((id > '02B66704-3CA7-4B94-9678-7087305DA45E')) ORDER BY id ASC LIMIT 2

Comment: Memory will be released i.e gc will be triggered only when almost all allocated memory is utilized...Try reducing allocated memory to jvm..

Comment: yes, i deploy the app and if I did not set the memory that it use to a big size, It just could not finish the migration and will throw an error like this: resource exhaustion；JVM Heap Memory could not be allocated. And when i monitor the process I found it just nearly use all the memory that allocated to the app

Comment: are you using an in-memory database for spring batch metadata?Which job repository are you using?

Comment: Yes we use a h2 database to store the spring batch data, like the job_exexcution data. Would this be the root cause?

Comment: yes, as this keeps on expanding in memory with time.We also faced a similar issue.

Comment: I tried to not use the memory data base, but it turns out that the memory usage still goes up very high, this should not be the root cause. I am for sure that spring batch just read all the data into the memory .

Comment: Try analyzing memory usage using heap console before jumping to conclusions!

Comment: Thanks, I am trying to analysis the gc logs and the heap memory.

Comment: Please let us know your findings!

Comment: Hi Sim, Just wanna to share with you that I have found the root cause of this issue. The paging reader did work. The reason it did not work is that I still call the cursor reader in my batch step. That was my fault,Sorry for the confusion and thanks for your help

Comment: Great Job! Glad you found the right root cause in the end!

Comment: Please make sure to upvote if I have helped you in any way.

Comment: Sure, thank you very much for your help Sim. It really helps

Answer (score 0):

The above code in the question did work and solve my memory issue, the reason it did not work is because I still calling the Cursor Reader in my spring batch step defination. So the paging reader can solve the memory issue